# PHP/MySQL mailing list, mailer and subscription classes

Tags: php, mysql, scripting, newsletter, subscription

I am working on a project that needs a emailable mailing list built into it with a very complex list structure. Originally I thought I could just use PHPList to do the job with some minor alterations because of its list management. But now I'm finding that I'm going to need to build this from scratch. PHPList is way to complex to make tweaks to.

So I'm looking for recommendations of scripts, classes, functions to help with the processes so I can just focus on the logic and list management.

The requirements are as follows:

1. **User Subscription** web form that captures name and email. Double opt-in that sends a confirmation email with a link back to a landing page. (Looking for a simple script to manage this aspect).
2. **Landing page** for opt-in confirmation from subscription email. This is where I need to include my list structure. The lists are very deep nested set trees and way beyond the scope of any mailing list I've come across. I'll need to build this part as it is too complex.
3. **User login** for future tweaking of their list settings. Would like a script to help with this aspect.
4. **Admin page** for constructing the email (html format). Looking for a simple script to help with this process. The site uses CKEditor for most html input so I could just end up using that here. I also then need to link it to the nested set tree list so I'll need to construct this portion myself. Looking for a simple class/script that I can use as a starting point to help with the structure.
5. **Mail manager** script. Ideally would like a cron job option to send the emails at a certain time each day/week. Also would like it to stagger the emails with a pause every 25 or so to bypass spam flags. A log file of what got sent where would be ideal. I'll need to construct the logic of what gets sent where because of the list structure. Would like an existing management script as a starting point.
6. **Mailer script**. Finally need a class/script to do the actual sending. I've used phpmailer in the past but wondered if there was anything better nowadays.

As I said at the start, PHPList is reasonably close but was far too complicated in its structure to be delving and changing the way it handles the lists. As such I'm looking for scripts that are user-friendly to tweak and hack.

Comment: Just found poMMo mailing list software. On first glance it is looking very well structured and easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents on this:

1. use utf-8 for all the system
2. normalize your emails
3. create a master suppression list
   (many domains wont like you sending
   emails to them. with this you can
   avoid send emails to people who
   probably will block you)
4. sending emails: create a queue:
   divide the process in stages: email
   rendering / email sending / etc
5. phpmailer is enough good
6. abuse of the use of the
   "List-unsubscribe" header and many
   others
7. create a [really good bounce handling
   script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011714/bounce-email-handling-with-php/1013000#1013000) (since keep sending to bad
   addresses kill the reputation)
8. setup you rdns for all your sending
   ips
9. use spf and DKYM
10. clean the email's body from bad
     user input.... some users will try
     to send "embed" tags on the body..
     that kill the sender reputation
11. follow all ISP/ESP instructions
     about: email per connections /
     timeouts / etc ..... yahoo! has it
     as many others ISP