# How to handle email address status in PHP?

Tags: php, email, email-client

I'm developing an email marketing system which allows users to send emails to multiple addresses. I have a list of tasks that need to be done, probably I will have many questions regarding to these tasks. Here's one of them: As I said, users are sending out emails to multiple addresses. **I want to check for every sent out emails if the receipient address blocks the email and the reason of the block.**

Usually this is coming back to an email from Mail Delivery System. I think the solution has to be somewhere around the idea of checking the incoming emails somehow. Please help me finding the best solution.

Thanks

```
**
```

- ### UPDATE:

**

I'm going to update the content of the question. I forgot to say that these emails are sent our from a valid SMTP server with username and password, there should be a way to get the content of inbox from PHP somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to check for every sent out emails if the receipient address blocks the email and the reason of the block.

Forget it. Most spam filters will just swallow unwanted E-Mail without comment (so as to not give spammers any hint about their success or failure).

Also, you won't be able to find out if a user simply deleted your E-Mail straight away, or had a rule set up in their E-Mail client to delete it. This is information that you will never get hold of unless the recipient tells you.

Only a tiniest fraction of rejected E-Mails will actually cause a reply to go out to the E-Mail sender address - if any! I, for one, have had mails swallowed by spam filters, but I've never received a reply saying "your E-Mail was filtered as spam". Have you?

What you *can* do is catch E-Mails whose delivery failed for technical reasons -  unknown recipient, recipient mailbox full, relaying failed... Those will be returned as "mailer-daemon" error messages to either the sender address, or the address specified in the `errors-to` header. Those mails you could parse using PHP. But I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Starts good. That's exactly what I want to know: if it fails because of an error. Can I somehow do that automatically after sending out the emails from PHP? I'm going to update the content of the question. I forgot to say that these emails are sent our from a valid SMTP server with username and password, there should be a way to get the content of inbox from PHP somehow.

Comment: As a follow-up: It think it's really hard to parse bounce messages. You could write a parser for the most common errors (recipient not found, mailbox full etc), but it would require a lot of time and effort doing so since there's no real standard. The most common way is to use a unique sender address (Return-Path) for each message so you can see that there are coming a bounce error for some recipients (but not WHY it bounced).

Comment: @Ervin @Emil already says it well: It's hard to parse the bounce messages, but it should be possible to find out whether there has been an error. See  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011714/bounce-email-handling-with-php