# Configuring a bounce e-mail for PHPMailer

Tags: php, email

I'm currently developing a newsletter system and I would like to set a bounce address. I'm using PHPMailer. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: looks same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011714/bounce-email-handling-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer Link:

http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html

also see stack overflow post :

[Bounce Email handling with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011714/bounce-email-handling-with-php)

I hope it will help u.