# Swiftmailer 4 does not retrieve bounces as $failedRecipients

Tags: php, sendmail, swiftmailer

I am trying this code (from http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html):

```
    require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

//Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25);

//Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

//Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

//Send the message
$failedRecipients = array();
$numSent = 0;
$to = array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@baddomain.org' => 'A name');

foreach ($to as $address => $name)
{
  $message->setTo(array($address => $name));
  $numSent += $this->send($message, $failedRecipients);
}

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);
```

The problem is that if I sent an email to a bad domain swiftmailer recognize it as a correct sent email and `$failedRecipients` is empty. In my mail box I have returned a failure notice.

Why does Swiftmailer not recognize this mail as as a failure, and does not populate `$failedRecipients` `Array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swiftmailer only takes care to hand the email over to the mail-server. Everything else is not related to Swiftmailer.

What you get is a bounce message, and you need to process them on your own, because the email itself actually was a syntactically mail address that was not rejected by the *first* server.

That btw is the case for any other mailing library and even the php `mail` function. You might be looking for a bounce processing application or code.

Related: [Bounce Email handling with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011714/bounce-email-handling-with-php)

Comment: Exactly. There's nothing that SwiftMailer (or any other library) can do if the mail server *accepts* the message in the first place.