# Laravel: Get bad_domains from Mailable

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I am sending mails with Laravel like this:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
   \Mail::to($user())->send(new Newsletter($user));
}
```

I would like to have an array of all the users who had a bad_domain response. I found in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#introduction) that Laravel uses Swiftmailer which has [a way to find bad_domain respones](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html#getting-failures-by-reference):

```
// Pass a variable name to the send() method
if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
{
  echo "Failures:";
  print_r($failures);
}

/*
Failures:
Array (
  0 => receiver@bad-domain.org,
  1 => other-receiver@bad-domain.org
)
*/
```

However, I want to use the a Mailable class. I am not sure how I can do this with the Swiftmailer (which I can access through \Mail::getSwiftMailer()).

Is there any easy way of getting the bad_domains when using Mailable from Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You may only access bad_domains, but not bounces with Swiftmailer ([Swiftmailer 4 does not retrieve bounces as $failedRecipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995785/swiftmailer-4-does-not-retrieve-bounces-as-failedrecipients?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

One can get *bad_domains*  it with

```
\Mail::to($user)->send(new \App\Mail\Hi());

dd(\Mail::failures());
```

See `Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php`

```
  /**
     * Send a Swift Message instance.
     *
     * @param  \Swift_Message  $message
     * @return void
     */
    protected function sendSwiftMessage($message)
    {
        try {
            return $this->swift->send($message, $this->failedRecipients);
        } finally {
            $this->forceReconnection();
        }
    }
```