# How to manage emails bouncing and errors in PHP?

Tags: php, email-client

What would be the best way to manage the emails bounces/errors if you are building a web-mass-mailing software ? I plan to use PHP for that.

Before someone start screaming, yes, the lists will be from valid customers who have opt-in.

I know there are desktop software or third party website that can manage such things. I would like to display it with a design similar to the current CMS's visual and be accessible in there.

If the only solution is to connect to a mail server and read the bouncing back messages, then I will head that way. Then, how would you parse the data to flag that email as "invalid"?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `best way to manage`? manage what?

Comment: @Paul, bouncing emails? Emails that have bounced back to the server either because the destination doesn't exists anymore or it's unreachable

Comment: Even out-of-offices may be considered a bounce back but those will be ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. What do you mean by "Manage"? Do you want to display bounced emails in a list? Do you want to remove them? Your question is very ambiguous.

Comment: @Paul, I wasn't specific enough I agree. But in both case it's the same story right?

Comment: @Paul: "Manage" could mean both of those things. If you don't know the answer, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible thing you could do aside from having a PHP script read mail from a pop/imap server would be to pipe incoming mail for a certain address to a php script. <sup>[See Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=pipe+email+to+php)</sup>

You would then read the entire contents of the message in by doing something like `$email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');`  I've installed the php extension [mailparse](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php) to assist in parsing RFC emails, but there are other options available.  You don't even necessarily have to use anything to parse the message.

Once you have the message, there are a number of indicators you can use to try to flag a message as a bounch.  First, see the Wikipedia article about [Non Delivery Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report), specifically [Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report#Format) and [RFC 6522 - The Multipart/Report Media Type for the Reporting of Mail System Administrative Messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6522).  You can also check for common headers in the message such as `X-Failed-Recipients` or `Diagnostic-Code`.

Once you've determined a message as a bounce in the PHP mail processor, you can take appropriate action and set a flag in the database related to that email.  Mind you, some errors may not mean the address is no good.  For example, if a mail server is down for a few days, your MTA may give up, but it doesn't mean the address is no good.  Also a user's mailbox could be full.

It wouldn't be a bad idea to log a copy of the bounced message so it could be checked by a person if necessary to diagnose an issue or reverse the flagging or a particular email address.

Here are some additional references:

http://forums.theplanet.com/lofiversion/index.php/t89873.html (note Improvement possibility 2)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700034/how-do-i-process-a-bounce-email-to-find-the-error-code
[Bounce Email handling with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011714/bounce-email-handling-with-php)

Hope that helps.